# Short Life of a Battery in a Solar Cell Garden Light

Tags: solar

I have the small garden lights with the LED lamp powered by a AA Ni-MH battery that is recharged by a solar panel on the top of the light fixture. These lights loose power and go dark within a couple hours of their turning on. Would I have better luck with Ni-Cd batteries?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't diagnosed the problem yet.

The problem isn't necessarily battery life. It could be available energy. If the solar panel isn't big enough, it's very likely that after a cloudy day it hasn't produced enough energy for the entire night.

Besides, short battery *life* (duration of providing power) doesn't mean you should change battery chemistry. Short battery lifetime means either the battery chemistry isn't good or you are charging it in an improper manner.

So if you find that the lights last entire night for the first 3 years and then don't anymore, the cause is that the batteries have a poor chemistry or you are charging them improperly.

If the battery *life* (as opposed to *lifetime*) is bad, then the cause is either that (1) you need bigger battery or more batteries, or (2) the solar panel can't produce enough power for the day.

To diagnose which is the cause, you need to do some information gathering. First, find out the capacity in watt hours of your battery bank. Usually the batteries state on a label the capacity in mAh or Ah, multiply by voltage to get mWh or Wh. Then find out the power usage of the light. For this you need a multimeter or a power meter.

Then you know how long theoretically the light should last on battery power. You should aim for as many hours as it's dark during the night plus some extra safety margin.

If the calculation showed the light doesn't last an entire night on battery power, then you know the cause: too few batteries. But if the calculation showed that you have enough duration for the entire night but the light still doesn't really last that long, you know you have too few solar panels. In this case, you need to install more panels.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The battery is a AA, 1.2 V 700mAh and that is the one that came with the light fixture. The solar array is also the one that came with the light & is probably 4”x4” on the top of the fixture. Therefore there is no way to add batteries or increase the size of the solar array. “Life” vs “Lifetime”, the light fixtures are less than 1 year old, and the lights only stay lit for about 2-3 hours